# implement spring-security-oauth2 on web application (server+client same application )

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am new to oauth2. I have tried hard to understand oauth2 and partly succeeded.
Now the requirement is to have my website outh2 implemented.
I have done the configuration of the server (minimal). The resources are protected and require authorization prior to access.
But how to get the client integrated on the same application?
what would be the best approach to go with?

To be specific I need to know once i have the authorization server up protecting my resources how the communication should follow from the client which are my jsp pages to my server.
Client would send username and password and server need to resolve it and call the internal authorization server and provide client with the access_token. Also what is the best approach to communicate access_token to/from client.
Thanks in advance.

my config file

```
<!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
      authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                   after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected
    and what roles have access to them -->
<http pattern="/abc/**" create-session="never"
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/abc/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
                        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>


<!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password
    combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users
    credentials from DB -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="iconnect" password="iconnect" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>


<!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now
    but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity
    and other things -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory" />
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                       resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                  authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
                  authorities="ROLE_APP" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                  authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
                  secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the
        http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow - please try to restrict the scope of your question :-)

Comment: Thanks Docteur. Following your advice i have tried to narrow the scope.

Comment: did not get an appropriate solution. We had to switch back to spring security. Still not sure if this kind of setup is appropriate for oauth2